# Remove old user from Remote Login permissions list

Tags: macos, sharing, ssh, user-account, system-settings

On OS X 10.8 I deleted a user account which had Remote Login permissions.  Now, in the Sharing tab of System Preferences, that user shows up as "Unknown User", and clicking the minus button won't remove it.[image]

Comment: The list is maintained by the directory services.  See the accepted answer to http://superuser.com/questions/166179/how-to-enable-remote-access-for-another-account-on-mac-remotely-via-ssh for some more details.

Comment: @Kent it seems normal to have *Unknown User* in the `/Local/Default` node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4169394?start=0&tstart=0), hope this helps.

1) First remove all users that can be removed from GUI In System Preferences -> Sharing -> Remote login

2) Run the below command which shows the configuration of users who have remote login access

```
sudo dscl  . -read /Groups/com.apple.access_ssh
```

example result:

```
AppleMetaNodeLocation: /Local/Default
GeneratedUID: 2F60778C-0931-47A4-B656-DBE07ACD843F
GroupMembers: **3D7C31B1-DEDE-4A5A-AAA8-CDD55645DC75**
GroupMembership: youraccoutname
PrimaryGroupID: 404
RealName:
Remote Login ACL
RecordName: com.apple.access_ssh
RecordType: dsRecTypeStandard:Groups
```

3) remove the group GroupMembers that the user(Unknown User) is in

```
sudo dscl  . delete /Groups/com.apple.access_ssh GroupMembers 3D7C31B1-DEDE-4A5A-AAA8-CDD55645DC75
```

4) Go to System preferences and see the result

Comment: Thank you!  It worked.  That command removed the entry from the Sys Prefs GUI, but running the dscl read command again still showed the old username.  So I opened up Directory Utility and deleted it there, from the Group called Remote Login ACL.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding upon [Kent's comment](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/93307/remove-old-user-from-remote-login-permissions-list#comment109490_93307), if you prefer a graphical user interface:

In the Users & Groups pane of System Preferences, click Login Options.

If the Edit… button is greyed out, then click the lock to make changes.

Edit… > Open Directory Utility…

## With Directory Utility

Click Directory Editor, then view Users in the /Local/Default node:

[image: A screenshot of Directory Utility]

### If you find debris that relates to the previously deleted user

You can authenticate and use Directory Utility to delete that debris.

### If you find no such debris

There may be an issue with a configuration file …

Comment: Thanks. I did find "Unknown User" in the Directory Editor, but after deleting it and rebooting, the problem still shows in Sharing prefs.

Comment: Please **vote down** this answer – sorry! *Unknown User* seems to be [normal for some installations of OS X](http://opensource.apple.com/source/files/files-553/private/etc/master.passwd). It may be appropriate to recreate *Unknown User* to have it reappear in Directory Utility – then revisit the opening question with a different answer.

Comment: @GrahamPerrin  if you know it is wrong why don't you delete the answer?

Comment: Leaving the answer could help to avoid others making the same mistake …